# Grep4j for zgrep ie., grepping archived log files

Tags: java, grep

I'm using `"Grep4J`" library to grep logs from linux servers. But i want to grep even in "gz" files which are nothing but archived log files.

By default, Grep4J not grepping inside tgz files and also i don't see any option to specify that. Simply, I need "zgrep" equivalent using `grep4j` library.

I'm using below command as of now:

```
grep(constantExpression("my grep string"), on(finalProfile));
```

I'm open to use any other java libraries which support this feature. Please don't suggest to use `Runtime.exec()` as i'm already aware this and my requirement is much more complex than executing simple command in linux.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through the source code of `grep4j`. It by default supports ".gz" files also. It is using "gunzip" instead of "zgrep". It seems some of my gz files are improper, due to that it is unable to read content from the those files.

Hope this helps someone who thinks like me, i'e, grep4j library doesn't support gz files.

Answer (score -2):

Do not use another weird libraries for that.
You could call any shell command from java, and get output with:

```
 Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping google.de");

BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
String s;
while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Then, just call any normal linux shell commands, (zgrep instead of ping in this example), whatever, from Java like that.

Comment: Hi.. I'm aware of this. I want to use that library to avoid re-writing all this piece of logic and also i need this in remote servers where i cannot write programs like this. Grep4j satisfies my needs except that zgrep.